# I cant divide 1 row from 3 columns in wordpress with footer theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system, parent-child

i have a problem with this dividing 1 row with 3 columns. My code is actualy good, but i am wondering why it didn't work. I am using child template in wordpress and i was trying to divide the  footer into 3 columns. Here is my code

```
<div class="footer section large-padding bg-dark">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="icon-top red-text">
            </div>
            <div class="zerif-footer-address"><center>Company address</center></div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="icon-top red-text">
            </div>
            <div class="zerif-footer-address"><center>Company address</center></div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="icon-top red-text">
            </div>
            <div class="zerif-footer-address"><center>Company address</center></div>
        </div>
</div>
    </div> <!-- /footer -->
```

my override css from parent is here :

```
/*
Theme Name:     Hemingway - Child Theme
Description:    Heminway Child Theme
Author:         john
Template:       hemingway

(optional values you can add: Theme URI, Author URI, Version, License, License URI, Tags, Text Domain)
*/
.credits-inner {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: initial;    
}
.footer {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
.company-details {
    width: 33%;
}
```

the output of the code is here :
[image: Output of the code]

Comment: use col-md-4 for each then it should be = 100%

Comment: i already tried, the output is still that in my screenshot

Comment: remove the css .company-details col-md-4 is bootstrap class it should apply bootstrap css

Comment: i think this theme doesn't apply bootstrap

Comment: Can you check in CHrome Inspector or Firefox FIrebug to see if the classes are even being applied. Also check if the bootstrap stylesheet is being enqueued or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are not using bootstrap css thats why your element are not floting left if you are not using bootstrap then apply this css

```
.row{
 widht: 100%;
}
.col-md-4 {
  flot:left;
  width:33.3333%;
}
```